# Word for sensation of lifting an unexpectedly light object?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a term for the sensation of *lifting an object that is unexpectedly lighter than it appeared?* For instance, picking up a can that you thought was full but was actually empty. The can seems to jump up weightlessly in your hand.

Does English have a specific word or term for this experience/event?

Comment: What a great question!  sort of a "false lift" feeling.

Comment: I'd use "relief"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *[size-weight illusion](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Size%E2%80%93weight_illusion)* can explain the sensation you are describing:

> - *The size–weight illusion, also known as the Charpentier illusion, is named after the French physician Augustin Charpentier  because he was the first to demonstrate the illusion experimentally.*
> - *These illusions can all be described as contrast with the expected weight*. The expected weight or density can be measured by matching visible and hidden weights, lifted in the same manner.
> - An early explanation of these illusions was that people judge the weight of an object from its appearance and then lift it with a pre-determined force. *They expect a larger object to be heavier and therefore lift it with greater force: the larger object is then lifted more easily than the smaller one, causing it to be perceived as lighter.*

Source: wwww.en.m.wikipedia.org

Answer (score 2):

Merrion Webster has an entry for **Overlift**; To lift an object **too much** (or too high)

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overlift (£$€)

[image]

As in, 'I thought the can was full so I *overlifted* it'

Comment: I would like to mark yours as the answer but that link is paywalled. Could you copy and paste it here?

Comment: You can see a real-world usage here; http://reynoldstechnology.biz/assets/pdf/rtl_2010_moto_tech.pdf *"So pleased were Reynolds with 
the results that showed its frame 
weighing in at 6.9kg, a full 1.5kg 
lighter than the previous one, 
that it was taken to the 2009 
Manx GP for public display. 
Everyone who picked it up 
‘overlifted’ it and was very 
surprised by the weight, or lack 
of it"*

Comment: Spectacular answer and find, Richard.  (BTW another totally awesome example of "insane voting on this site."  You provide the SWR answer of the week and someone .. downvotes it!)

Comment: @JoeBlow - I'm assuming it was DV'd because the link is paywalled.

Comment: If someone perceives an undeserved DV on another person's post, there's an little icon that can be clicked to mitigate the effect. Just sayin'.